# How to make border focused under menu on css?

Tags: html, css, hover, border

I am pretty new on css and I want to learn use css effectively but I have now couple of problems/questions, I want to make grey border under my menu but when I zoom in and out border behave so strangely? Sorry my code is not very clean. And how can I retouch my code for better standing?

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
span{
    color:#d00000;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#home{
    background-color:#0000CC;

}
span{
    font-style:italic;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">

<ul>
    <li><a href="#Home" id="home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#link2">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link3">link3</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#sub">sub</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sub2">sub2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li><!---End of DropDown Videos menu--->
    <li><a href="#link4">link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link5">link5</a></li>
</ul><!---End of nav elements--->
<br class="clearFloat">
</div><!---End of header--->
</div><!---End of wrapper--->
<div id="grey">
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
    float:center;
}
#grey{
    border-bottom:250px solid #a0a0a0;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:203px;
    margin-right:387px;

}

#header{
    margin:auto;
    padding:0px;
    clear:both;
}
#header ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    line-height:30px;

}
#header li{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#000099;
    border:1 solid #0000CC;
    top:px;
    right:-15%;
}

#header ul li a{
    text-align:center;
    font-family:fantasy;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    color:black;
}
#header ul ul li a{
    color:#0000cc;

}
#header ul ul li{
        right:0%;
}

#header ul ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    position:absolute;
        opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
}
#header ul li:hover ul {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity:1 ;
}
#header ul li:hover {
    background-color:blue;
}
#header ul li:hover a {
color:black;
}
#header ul ul li:hover a {
color:#d00000;
}
.clearfloat{
    clear:both;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

}
```

Comment: there is no property of  float:center; in css

Comment: Yeah I know that was just a test and I forgot to remove it.

Comment: i don't understand your problem

Comment: I try to make little grey border bottom the menu, when I zoom out menu gets smaller but grey border stretches horizontally?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with some of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Without completely reworking your code, just think of added a bottom border per 'li'...
Remove your id='grey' and add your border-bottom to your *#header li {}*. Refresh but note how your 'sub' menus then each have a bottom border now. They inherited it, so you then need to turn those off...hence add border-bottom: none to the *#header ul ul li* declaration.

Now...if we did a quick rework of your code...

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <div id="navwrapper">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="#Home" id="home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#link2">link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link3">link3</a>
                <ul class="sub">
                    <li><a href="#sub">sub</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#sub2">sub2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#link4">link4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link5">link5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body { margin:10px;padding:0; }

#wrapper, #header, #navwrapper { margin: 0 auto 0 auto; }

#nav {

    padding:0;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    line-height:30px;
    height:30px;
    list-style:none }

#nav li {
    border-bottom: solid #a0a0a0 10px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    background-color:#000099;
     }

#nav a {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:fantasy;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    width:150px;
    color:black;
}

#nav li:hover { background-color:blue; }

#nav li:hover .sub {
    visibility:visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

#nav .sub a { color:#00c; }

#nav .sub {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all .1s ease-in;
    list-style: none;
}

#nav .sub li { clear:both; border-bottom: none; }
```

Using more naming conventions with your sub menus is safer than just drilling down through the css. You also need to note that any top-level CSS declaration is inherited by all the children within. Such that if you declare *#nav li* as being black but want all the 'sub' list elements to be blue, that needs to be stated explicitly...AFTER the initial declaration in the CSS document.

Hope this helped...